# Can't run application in Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios-simulator, swift2

I have found myself in a little bit of trouble at the moment.
There seems to be some sort of bug with the new xCode and swift 2.0.

I'm trying to launch my app with the simulator but I get following error:

```
"The operation couldn't be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 1.)
```

Please observe that it's error 1 and not 4 ( which seem to be the most common one )

I'm using:

- OS: OS X Yosemite v. 10.10.4
- xCode: Version 7.0 beta ( 7A176x )
- Command Line Tools: xCode 7.0 ( 7A176x )
- Simulator: v 9.0 (SimulatorApp-620 CoreSimulator-179)

This project is purely done in swift 2.0 not been converted or anything.
I have tried "Reset contents and settings..."

I know there is a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350957/fbsopenapplicationerrordomain-error-1)  but there is no answers and I didn't want to make a "me too" - comment and not provide my information.

Funny thing tho.. Whenever I launched the simulator before ( pre swift 2.0 ) I had to enter administrator password, not anymore.

I can run the app, but it's not connected to xcode, so all the print() / NSLog things aren't passed down to xcode, so it doesn't print anything in the debug window.

So my questions are these:

1. Can anyone help me get my simulator working?
2. Can it be connected to privilege?
3. Can it be connected to the beta-release?

Comment: Have you tried a full clean - i.e. deleting the project's derived data (cmd-alt-shift-K) and restarting Xcode?

Comment: Yes I have tried that, didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I find this very annoying, I rely heavily on print() to tell me what's going on. And if xcode can't launch the app, xcode will not get those calls to print..

Comment: Please file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com, including the syslog for the relevant simulated device.

Comment: If you look at the syslog for the relevant device or CoreSimulator.log, there will likely be more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Facebook Frameworks? I mysteriously had to take that out of my app so I could archive it...Maybe you should do the same.