# Apps manually installed in simulator crashes upon load

Tags: xcode, installation, ios-simulator, xcode7, xcrun

I'm installing `MyApp` on the iOS simulator (Xcode 7, iOS 9) using `xcrun simctl install booted MyPath/MyApp.app`.

This works as expected and the app is installed on the simulator.

However, launching the app either manually or using `xcrun simctl launch booted com.company.MyApp` fails. Giving back the error:

> An error was encountered processing the command
>   (domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain, code=1): The operation couldn’t
>   be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 1.)

The app is exported from Xcode (note that running the app from Xcode or re-building the app from its source code is not a liable solution).

It's not app specific, as any app install in this manner crashes with the same error.

The system log reports the same error, but with some additional information.

> com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.CA35ED48-DDAA-4CF0-8C69-C206CC55A6EB.launchd_sim[4200]
>   (UIKitApplication:com.company.MyApp[0xe9ec][4281]): Program specified
>   by service does not contain one of the requested architectures: R
>
> SpringBoard[4217]: Unable to get pid for
>   'UIKitApplication:com.company.MyApp[0xe9ec]': No such process (err 3)
>
> SpringBoard[4217]: Bootstrapping failed for
>
> SpringBoard[4217]: Application
>   'UIKitApplication:com.company.MyApp[0xe9ec]' exited voluntarily.
>
> SpringBoard[4217]: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you
>   want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE
>   environmental variable.
>
> SpringBoard[4217]: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you
>   want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE
>   environmental variable.
>
> SpringBoard[4217]: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you
>   want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE
>   environmental variable.
>
> SpringBoard[4217]: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you
>   want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE
>   environmental variable.
>
> SpringBoard[4217]: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you
>   want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE
>   environmental variable.
>
> SpringBoard[4217]: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you
>   want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE
>   environmental variable.
>
> com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.CA35ED48-DDAA-4CF0-8C69-C206CC55A6EB.launchd_sim[4200]
>   (UIKitApplication:com.company.MyApp[0xc82f][4282]): Program specified
>   by service does not contain one of the requested architectures: R
>
> SpringBoard[4217]: Unable to get pid for
>   'UIKitApplication:com.company.MyApp[0xc82f]': No such process (err 3)
>
> SpringBoard[4217]: Bootstrapping failed for
>
> SpringBoard[4217]: Application
>   'UIKitApplication:com.company.MyApp[0xc82f]' exited voluntarily.

The `architectures` error varies the variable. R, f, etc.

What's the causing this issue? How may I resolve it?

Comment: This seems like the same issue you're seeing:https://discuss.appium.io/t/appium-v1-3-0-beta1-xcode-6-1-failed-looking-up-pid-of-launched-process/1015/5

Comment: Your App looks like is missing the required x86 architecture thats not something you can fix without recompiling the proyect.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem, but using Xamarin. In Visual Studio I solved it by going to the iOS project properties and under "iOS Build" I changed the "Supported architectures" from "i386" to "i386 + x86_64".

Hopefully you can adapt that to XCode.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this problem in Xcode 6 when using the .app file in directory "Release-iphoneos" instead of "Release-iphonesimulator". There are multiple versions of this file, and you need to change the path in your install command to point to the correct one.

If this .app file was sent to you by someone/something else, it may be a copy from the wrong directory (not built for a simulator)

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you use the wrong sdk. If the project is built using the physical device sdk it crashes on start up when you try to open it on the simulator.

If you are building it from the command line with xcrun xcodebuild check thet the sdk is "iphonesimulator" not "iphoneos"

e.g 

`xcrun xcodebuild -scheme <yourScheme> -configuration Debug -project <yourProject>.xcodeproj -sdk iphonesimulator build`

Answer (score 0):

when you say you export from Xcode, are you referring to export from iOS App Archive? if so you are missing an important fact that these package are build for iOS not Simulator which is totally different architecture as Nanoc pointed out.

**You are trying to achieve an impossible solution to your problem.**