# The operation couldn't be completed error for tvOS simulator

Tags: xcode, tvos

I am trying to build and run my app for tvOS , but Xcode keeps me this error :[image]

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain
>   error 1.)

I have to run again to install it on simulator , how should I fix this issue ? I have done these things :

- Clean code
- Deleted app and installed again
- Reset simulator content and stings

Comment: Have you tried these solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350957/fbsopenapplicationerrordomain-error-1

Comment: I found this answer interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32896457/3973645 Normally, this error has to do with scheme and running environment. If this works, remember to thank Denis (author of the post : ) Good Luck

Comment: I did ! but still getting error !

Comment: Sorry, the answer wasn't that helpful. I will try to think for other solutions. I had this problem when I first ran the app, my solution was rerun the app one more time. Everything it's fine after that.

Comment: I found this in the release note of Xcode 7.2 beat:                                   Testing
• UI tests fail to launch in the tvOS simulator if run with Unit Tests. Workaround: Run your UI tests
with their own scheme, separately from your unit tests. (23079718) Try the Xcode 7.2 beta if you could.