# Debugger not working on Apple Watch Series 3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, debugging, apple-watch

**Problem: I cannot get the Xcode debugger to attach to my new Apple Watch**

Hardware:

- Apple Watch Series 3 (no GPS)
- iPhone 6s

Where it works:

- Debugger works fine on the physical iPhone
- Simulators work great (both iPhone and Apple Watch)

**Things I've tried:**

- Restarting all three devices (Mac, iPhone, Apple Watch)
- Formatting and reinstalling iOS 11 on my iPhone
- Unpairing and repairing the Apple Watch (done this 1000 times)
- Completely removing all of Xcode and reinstalling from the app store (deleting simulators, sdks--everything)

Other things:

- I've made sure to trust this computer
- I've started a brand new project just to make sure it's not something in my code.

It shows up in Xcode as a valid target, but when I build it just says "Running App on Jason's Apple Watch." It installs the app, but doesn't start it, and the debugger doesn't hit any breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Attempt to attach the debugger manually to the Likely Targets.

XCode -> Debug -> Attach to Process -> Likely Targets -> Your Project

I had this same issue and am uncertain of why this started happening to me. If someone knows how to permanent fix this problem, please feel free to edit this answer.

[image: Attach to Likely Targets]

Comment: My watchApp builds and installs on the watch, but the debugger does not attach.
It was working fine up to a few days ago - maybe when I upgraded Xcode fro 9.3 to 9.4 Beta.
I have now reverted to 9.3 and the problem persists.
The Build and Run process terminates with "Finished running {app name} on Alan's Apple Watch. The app did not start on the watch.

Comment: I am using 9.4 and have to attach the process manually as shown above. Maybe it is a 9.4 problem.

Comment: And now I have installed Xcode 9.4 (release Version 9.4 (9F1027a), not Beta)  it's working fine again! Apple's QA is shit!

Answer (score 0):

It started working. Not sure what specific thing it was, but I enabled all the checks in the debugger scheme. Posting in case this helps someone else:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, only difference is my Watch is Series 0.  I have not had this issue with WatchOS 4.0 and have been testing my watch regularly over the past few weeks, so I thought it might be something related to Watch OS 4.1 which I installed yesterday but looking at your post Oct 29th was prior to the release, unless you were running the beta?

Comment: finally fixed it, this is what solved it for me:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350957/fbsopenapplicationerrordomain-error-1